# ui-grid: trigger sorting in custom header template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I use the following in order to implement custom column headers for my grid:

```
<div role="columnheader">
  <table class="table-header-rotated">
    <theader>
      <tr>
        <th class="op-table-group-heading rotate-45">
          <div class="op-table-group-heading-title rotated-container"
               ng-class="{inclined : col.headerCellClass}">
            <span>{{col.headerCellClass}}</span>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="op-table-asset-heading rotate-45">
          <div class="rotated-container colt{{col.uid}}">
            <span>{{col.displayName}}</span>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </theader>
  </table>
</div>
```

However, clicking on this header does not trigger any change to the sorting. A (probably outdated) article in the wiki suggests to use `col.sort()` in order to do so. However, doing this fails with `v2.sort is not a function`.

I have looked at the source code for the current default header templates in ui-grid 3. However, I can find no `ng-click` in it that would trigger the sort event, so I can only assume they are binding their click listeners somehwere else.

How do I go about enabling sorting in my custom template?

Comment: the sorting and other behaviour is a part of `headerCellTemplate`. You may want to use that instead of custom header template. More on this here - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Templating

Comment: I know, I mentioned the original template in my question. What I am trying to figure out is just which specific part(s) of it are responsible for triggering the sorting change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so after dissecting the original template, it seems that the one crucial component needed to trigger sorts when clicking the header is `ui-grid-cell-contents` class. Thus, the minimum header template that can be used for sorting is simply `<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"></div>`